# Defining Hibernate 5 FilterDefinition by code

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

We have a project using Hibernate 3.6.10, and now we are planning to upgrade the Hibernate version to 5.6.0.
One problem we have found is in old Hibernate it was possible to register `FilterDefinition` classes by code, but now I canoot find anyway to do that. So my question is how to register `FilterDefinition`s by code (not resolved from annotations or XML configs).

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it but it seems to be possible to programmatically add a filter definition into the metadata used to build the session factory:

```
private SessionFactory bootStrapSessionFactory(Configuration configuration) {
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = configuration.getStandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
            .build();

    Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
    FilterDefinition filterDefinition = ...
    metadata.getFilterDefinitions().put(key, filterDefinition);
    
    return metadata.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

I'm not quite sure why you need to build filters programmatically but the above code seems a bit like a hack